# Export PDF Telerik grid MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, telerik, telerik-grid

I have got a Telerik MVC grid and I would like to export it as a pdf and hide the column "Test2". I am not able to achieve the desired behavior.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Lagerbase.Models.Artikel>()
.Name("ArtikelGrid")
.ToolBar(tools => tools.Pdf())
    .Pdf(pdf => pdf
        .AllPages()
        .AvoidLinks()
        .PaperSize("A4")
        .Scale(0.8)
        .Margin("2cm", "1cm", "1cm", "1cm")
        .Landscape()
        .RepeatHeaders()
        .TemplateId("page-template")
        .FileName("Artikel.pdf")
        .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Pdf_Export_Save", "Grid"))
    )
   .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(o => o.Test1);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Test2);
        })
}
```

This is what I found for an Excel export. So I adjusted the bind to "pdfExport".
Unfortunately it doesn't work for the function `e.sender.saveAsExcel();`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var exportFlag = false;
        $("#ArtikelGrid").data("kendoGrid").bind("pdfExport", function (e) {
            if (!exportFlag) {
                e.sender.hideColumn(1);
                e.preventDefault();
                exportFlag = true;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    e.sender.saveAsExcel();
                });
            } else {
                e.sender.showColumn(1);
                exportFlag = false;
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Does someone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

View this Demo : [FUll demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/obUYa)

[Source](http://www.telerik.com/forums/export-to-grid-hide-columns)